# Incorrect shell password correct terminal password

Tags: command-line, gnome, login, password

I'm trying to make some changes from the ctrl+alt+f1 menu, but the shell only rejects my login ("login incorrect" message).  This is the same login and password that is accepted EVERYWHERE ELSE I'm asked for one.  No, it is not an error of my typing.  What is the deal?  I changed my computer's name recently, could that be getting in my way?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your keyboard settings are not exactly the same in the tty and elsewhere (layout, numeric pad use and so on).
I suggest you type your password in the login field in order to see how it looks really.

HTH